# Spark - how to optimize Row object for large number of columns in a RDD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on converting a fixed length file to csv using spark.

```
   val recs  = rdd.map(line => {

      convert_INPUT(line.getBytes())

    }


def convert_INPUT(record:Array[Byte] )=
  {

    val COL_1 = record.slice(0,0+16)
    val COL_2 = record.slice(16,16+1)
    val COL_3 = record.slice(17,17+3)
    val COL_ = record.slice(20,20+1)
    . . . . 
    . . . . 
    . . . . 
    val COL_1000 = record.slice(5200,5200+8)

    Row(COL_1,COl_2,COL_3......COL_1000)
}

recs.saveAsTextFile(outfile)
```

I have an RDD with Row object of 1000+ columns.. most of them are string and BigDecimal data types.The ROW object size could be approximated to around 5K. For an input file with 1GB size, is this Row size big enough to cause performance issues?.

I observe that the 1GB file takes almost 50 minutes to process it.. whereas similar RDD with less number of columns (<50) but 1GB in size completes quickly i.e 3 minutes.

Any fine-tuning available for 1000+ columns in a Row() object or the 5K size?.
Am I overlooking anything here?

Here is the summary printed for 1000+ columns

```
19/02/19 09:56:53 INFO rpc.b: Summary of connection to localhost:50505: RpcStats [name=localhost:50505, lifetimeStats=PeriodicStats [startTimeMillis=1550584572436, numMessages=0, numErrors=730, sumServiceTimeNanos=0, minNanos=2147483647, maxNanos=-2147483648, avg=0, adj=0], periodicStats=PeriodicStats [startTimeMillis=1550584572436, numMessages=0, numErrors=730, sumServiceTimeNanos=0, minNanos=2147483647, maxNanos=-2147483648, avg=0, adj=0], jsonSummaryStats=PeriodicStats [startTimeMillis=1550584572436, numMessages=0, numErrors=730, sumServiceTimeNanos=0, minNanos=2147483647, maxNanos=-2147483648, avg=0, adj=0], runningAverageMillis=0]
```

This one for the RDD with < 50 columns but 1 GB in size

```
19/02/19 10:23:49 INFO rpc.b: Summary of connection to localhost:50505: RpcStats [name=localhost:50505, lifetimeStats=PeriodicStats [startTimeMillis=1550589540572, numMessages=0, numErrors=59, sumServiceTimeNanos=0, minNanos=2147483647, maxNanos=-2147483648, avg=0, adj=0], periodicStats=PeriodicStats [startTimeMillis=1550589540572, numMessages=0, numErrors=59, sumServiceTimeNanos=0, minNanos=2147483647, maxNanos=-2147483648, avg=0, adj=0], jsonSummaryStats=PeriodicStats [startTimeMillis=1550589540572, numMessages=0, numErrors=59, sumServiceTimeNanos=0, minNanos=2147483647, maxNanos=-2147483648, avg=0, adj=0], runningAverageMillis=0]
```

Comment: It is not a common use case in data processing of having 1000+ columns. We have a data model of fewer than 200 columns and having issues processing them. I guess you need to clarify why 1000+ columns in String and BigDecimal? I haven't voted the question, but could understand why it got -1.

Comment: @ Iraj Hedayati, it is a kind of business scenario - history of 12 months of various amount fields of a customer transactions...

Comment: @ Iraj Hedayati .. how did you address those issues in your project.

Comment: We took two different approaches: 1) use nested types (but it would be hard for you as your output is CSV 2) we did optimization in the code. As our friend mentioned, it is most of the time how you employ Spark in your project could cause performance issues. You may need to share part of the code that does processing.

Comment: i use ````recs.saveAsTextFile(outfile)```` to write it as text file.. Could you uplease help in wrapping the Encoder?..

Comment: So you don't use Spark SQL at all. What is even the reason to use `Row`. Also does your code literally look like the one in question, with all the cases explicitly enumerated?

Comment: Actually each column is wrapped in another function like big(record.slice...).. which return s value to COL_l. That's is the difference..

Comment: There is a future requirement to store it as parquet file as well.. that's the reason I used Row

Comment: In general the code you've shown so far doesn't indicate any relation to known Spark SQL issues. So it suggests that problem is in fact the parsing code. I'd strongly suggest running `convert_INPUT` in isolation with your favorite profiler to determine which elements are a bottleneck.

Comment: The scope of the problem is not specific to be answered in one question! My opinion is you need some experts to re-evaluate the situation. You need to have the full picture of source data, source schema, transformations, writing, Spark job evaluation and etc.! Sorry, I can't be any of help here anymore.

Comment: My 5 cents. I wonder if it would be possible for you to load the fixed length csv file directly into DataFrame as single string column and then process the creation of columns with FoldLeft where each fold takes the required substring and casts to required type. Maybe solution like this would give you some speed up.

Comment: Have you tried creating a Hive external table with RegexSerde and accessing that Hive table in Spark?

Comment: How is RDD (input) is being generated. Is RDD fully materialized before performing convert_INPUT ?? Else bottleneck could potentially exists while calculating input RDD itself.

Comment: As mentioned in the question.. input is a fixed length file..not RDD

Comment: Without sample data, it is not possible to reproduce the issue. I'd suggest you to add 1 sample record in question so that a record can be copied over multiple times while creating large data for reproducing the issue